# Multidimensional Obj or Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I need help with multidimensional Array or Object.

This is my code:

```
let Calcoli = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
  add_array("Home",  '+', 15, "");
  add_array("Car",   '+', 15, "");
  add_array("Music", '+', 40, 0);
  add_array("Music", '+', 50, 1);
  debug_obj(Calcoli);
});

function add_array(keys, op, value, i) {
  if (i != ""){
    if (isNaN(Calcoli[keys][i])) {          
      Calcoli[keys] = [];
      Calcoli[keys][i] = 0;
    }
    if (op == "+") { 
        Calcoli[keys][i] += value;
    }
  } else {
    if (op == "+") {
      Calcoli[keys] += value;
    }
  }
}

function debug_obj(item) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

The result is:

```
{"Home":30,"Car":15,"Music":[null,50]}
```

and I need

```
{"Home":30,"Car":15,"Music":[40,50]} –
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: The result is: {"Home":30,"Car":15,"Music":[null,50]} and i need {"Home":30,"Car":15,"Music":[40,50]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You're not initializing the value in your `else` case, so you're adding to an undefined number, getting `NaN`
2. `if (i != 0)` will actually fail when `i == ""`, as they're both "falsey" and will compare as equals.

Initialize all of your objects when needed, check your values in a type-safe manner, and skip some `if`s...

```js
let Calcoli = {};

add_array("Home", '+', 15, "");
add_array("Car", '+', 15, "");
add_array("Music", '+', 40, 0);
add_array("Music", '+', 50, 1);
debug_obj(Calcoli);

function add_array(keys, op, value, i) {
  if (i !== "") {
    Calcoli[keys] = Calcoli[keys] || []
    Calcoli[keys][i] = Calcoli[keys][i] || 0
    
    if (op == "+") {
      Calcoli[keys][i] += value;
    }
  } else {
    Calcoli[keys] = Calcoli[keys] || 0

    if (op == "+") {
      Calcoli[keys] += value;
    }
  }
}

function debug_obj(item) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: Works FIne. Thanks Paul ;)

Comment: This is safer but still not safe, and you will fight a losing battle trying to make it safe because the concept is unsafe. There's nothing to prevent a property being initialised as an array, eg `add_array("Home", '', 15, 1)` and subsequently commanded as a value `add_array("Home", '+', 1, "")`.

Comment: True. There's also nothing in the code that *does* that, though, and the intent of the answer was to clarify to the OP what's causing the problems they actually see, and how those might be prevented.

Comment: @PaulRoub, absolutely. No criticism. My comment was really meant for the OP.